# Delete duplicates across rows data.table

Tags: r, data.table

After a lot of operations. I have:

```
dput(result_wide)
structure(list(Node = c("Sante", "Federica", "Filippo", "Francesco", 
"Giovanni", "Marina", "Mario", "Teresa", "Tommaso", "Alex"), 
    `1` = c("Mario", "Mario", "Mario", "Giovanni", "Teresa", 
    "Mario", "Giovanni", "Giovanni", "Mario", "0"), `2` = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Filippo", "0", "0", "0"), `3` = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "Mario", "Francesco", "0", "Giovanni", "Mario", 
    "0", "0"), `4` = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "Teresa", "0", "Teresa", 
    "Giovanni", "0", "0"), `5` = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "Mario", 
    "0", "Teresa", "Mario", "0", "0"), `6` = c("0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "Mario", "0", "Tommaso", "0", "0", "0"), `7` = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Marina", "0", "0", "0"), `8` = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Federica", "0", "0", "0"), `9` = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Sante", "0", "0", "0"), `10` = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Francesco", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x562191bd8c70>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

This is very close to what I want. Except for the duplicates across rows.

How can I replace with missing values those duplicates **across rows**?

Comment: Two things, please: (1) your question has everything to do with `data.table` and reducing duplicates row-wise, and we need none of the code you have to generate it (too complex), I suggest in this case just provide an unambiguous sample of data (using `dput`, `data.frame`, `read.table`, or `fread`). (2) Asterisks are good for identifying the problem areas, but since we can't use the code anyway (missing `graph` for starters), we resort to trying to scrape the "My output" frame, which means we must manually edit it to get what we _think_ you actually have. Tis better to use `dput` or such. Thx!

Comment: @r2evans I still think that tweaking appropriately the igraph (now omitted) part could have given me the output suggested in Ric Villalba answer. But since he's provided the answer I edited as per your request and I'll keep in mind next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.data.table(t(apply(result_wide, 1,\(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))))
```

Comment: Inferring the `"0"` might be immune from deduplication, one might use `replace(x, x != "0" & duplicated(x), NA)` instead. Further inferring that the default should be `"0"` instead of `NA`, perhaps `replace(x, x != "0" & duplicated(x), "0")` is good enough?

Comment: Good points. Also, because of the **asterisks** I do not get if the user wants to replace all but the first or all but the last duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I see asterisks a lot when the user thinks highlighting them in raw data will make them bold or at least stand out ... requiring manual editing. Good intentions gone afoul.

Comment: Sorry for the asterisks, it was to highlight duplicated values. It doesn't matter to me the first or the last is the same I tried with duplicated but couldn't figure out how to apply correctly `filtered <- transpose(result_wide[,])
transpose(filtered[,lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))])`